# Javascript: How can I reliably derive ImageData from base64?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following MWE:

```
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var str = "data:image/png;base64,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"
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = str;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    console.log('imageDataxD', imageData.data);
```

It runs roughly 40% of the time when testing locally in my browser. The error that I am getting states:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.
```

Why is the code receiving the width sometimes, and sometimes not?

Comment: Maybe waiting for load event is required. I guess onload also waits for bitmap allocation & rendering of data, not just downloading from an url.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik could you recommend where I could put such a code block / how it might look?

Comment: All you have to do is set a callback like `image.onload = () => { /* code below image.src = str */ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image onload event is required to work on bits of bitmap:

```
imgage.onload = function() {
   // do work 
};
image.src = "base64 code here";
```

Because when setting src, it downloads/gets content, allocates memory for bitmap, initializes the bitmap, then calls the onload.

There shouldn't be any problem if you set the onload function before setting src.